# Is it possible to draw chart and other data in the same sheet with phpexcel?

Tags: charts, phpexcel

Is it possible to draw chart and other data in the same sheet with phpexcel? if yes, so how to address library function to draw chart after or left/right side of other data?

Comment: Try taking a look at the myriad of examples for creating charts that are found in the `/Examples` folder, e.g. `33chartcreate-line.php`

Comment: Blog posts like [this one](http://designdrizzle.com/how-to-easily-generate-charts-and-excel-files-with-phpexcel/) might also show you how to create a worksheet with a chart